# Caterpillar/Worm/Moth Larva eating my Petunias

Tags: flowers, pest-control

Will I be able to take care of the issue by vigilantly hunting these creatures (which manages my snail problem fairly well), or do I need chemicals, mantises, Wile E. Coyote style traps, etc.?

Most of the damage is confined to the flower part of the plant.  A few leaves have a few bites taken out, but they dont seem interested in eating the green part.  They tend to hide in the.... shaft?-of the flower.  They are visually similar to the worms in [this](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/39648/26207) question.  Size is roughly .5cm to 1cm.  The plants are planted in the ground, not a hanging basket.    Located in New Mexico, USA.  [This](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/35652/26207) question doesn't really help.  Some Photos:

[image]

[image]
It's sort of hard to see in this photo, its holding onto the... Stamen?  Pistol?  Growy part with seeds on the end.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Every time I plant petunias I prepare for my battle against the *budworms* (they are actually caterpillars).

These caterpillars are voracious and will cause extensive damage quickly. I have tried a few homemade "safer/greener" concoctions, none of which worked. Pesticide spray listed for *budworms* works the best for me.